# Bootstrap overflow issue

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

How do I stop my bootstrap from stopping when I side scroll on my tablet?

When the page loads it looks fine but when when I scroll to the left to see the end of my table, the background an divs stop.

[image: Screen Shot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use a Bootstrap class for .table wrapping  class

```
.table-responsive
```

something like this

```
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table">
    ...
  </table>
 </div>
```

Comment: if it wasn't in a table but ran over what could I use?